# Cannot add Expires Headers to Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to add the expires headers for images and css/js to my Nginx configuration. But Once I add it, it brakes eveything and I cannot get the website correctly.

This is my nginx.con

```
    worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    #BUFFER SIZE
    client_body_buffer_size      128k;
    client_max_body_size         10m;
    client_header_buffer_size    1k;
    large_client_header_buffers  4 4k;
    output_buffers               1 32k;
    postpone_output              1460;

    # server_tokens off;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log;

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
    open_file_cache_errors off;

    # Enable Gzip
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers     4 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
    text/css
    text/javascript
    text/xml
    text/plain
    text/x-component
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    font/truetype
    font/opentype
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/svg+xml;



    gzip_proxied        expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary           on;


        ### Proxy Settings

    #    proxy_cache_path  /usr/local/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
    #    proxy_temp_path /usr/local/nginx/cache/tmp;
    #    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
    #    proxy_cache_valid 500 502 504 5m;
    #    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 1w;
    #    expires 1w;
    #    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    #    charset utf-8;



    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here the server configuration :

```
 map $scheme $hsts_header {
    http   max-age=31536000;
 }
 server {
    listen 80;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #index index.html index.htm;

    include includes/pageSpeedConfig;
    include includes/redirects;
    include includes/static-cache;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security $hsts_header;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000 always;

        location /probepage {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        error_page  500 502 503 504 /502.html;
        location = /502.html {
                root  /usr/local/nginx;

        }

    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        location / {                
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout      90;
                proxy_send_timeout         90;
                proxy_read_timeout         90;
                proxy_buffer_size          4k;
                proxy_buffers              4 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            proxy_temp_path            /usr/local/nginx/proxy;
    }

 }
```

and here the configuration for adding the expires static-cache file include :

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

I'm not including the https server, as this is the test server.

Can you please help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "It brakes everything" is not really helpful to get to the problem - what happens, error messages in the log, etc.?

Comment: It just does not load css correctly, so the page seems broken. Nothing on the logs